# How to search for a key in multi valued array in php array_search()?

Tags: php, arrays

while doing array search in php array search

i need to search the key for the value blue

but key for both values purple, blue

when i try the following it shows nothing

```
$array = array(1 => 'orange', 2 => 'yellow', 3 => 'green', 4 => 'purple','blue');

$key = array_search('blue', $array);  

echo $key;
```

How to find the key for blue or do i need to change the `$array`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)

Comment: @kumar_v He doesn't have a multi-dimensional array, it's just an ordinary associative array.

Comment: @StackExchange https://eval.in/87552 it's return 5

Comment: A key can only have one value in an associative array. You're confused if you think that `4` is the key for both purple and blue.

Comment: @kumar_v anna i need to find the key as 4 when i search for purple or blue ! how to do this

Comment: Why don't you make the colors the keys and the numbers the values?

Comment: @Barmar fine . simple , what i want is i have two values and they should return same key . how to do this ?

Comment: Do you mean `... 3 => 'green', 4 => array('purple', 'blue'));`?

Comment: One key can't map to two values. It can map to an array, as @TiMESPLiNTER showed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the maximum user assigned key is **4** i.e. purple, so it will be **5** for blue eventually... and the code what you are using exactly returns the right output which is **`5`**.

If you do `print_r()` of your array you will get the idea.. See here

```
Array
(
    [1] => orange
    [2] => yellow
    [3] => green
    [4] => purple
    [5] => blue
)
```

**`EDIT :`**

> i need to find the key as 4 when i search for purple or blue ! how to
>   do this

### You cannot have a same key in an array or for two different values !

Instead modify your array like this...

```
<?php
$array = array(1 => 'orange', 2 => 'yellow', 3 => 'green', 4 => 'purple,blue'); //Adding purple and blue seperated by comma...

foreach($array as $k=>$v)
  {
   if(strpos($v,'purple')!==false)
    {
     echo $k;// "prints" 4 if you pass purple or blue !
     break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please indent your code. I'm used to questioners not doing this, answerers should be better.

Answer (score 1):

First, the program you show as an example will output 5 as the key value for 'blue', as others have already pointed out.

Now if I understand what you might want, it's a way of having two elements referred to by the same index.

In that case you could simply swap keys and values, like so:

```
$array = array(
    'orange' => 1,
    'yellow' => 2,
    'green'  => 3,
    'purple' => 4,
    'blue'   => 4);

echo $array['purple']; // 4
echo $array['blue'  ]; // 4
```